# Number of characters matching between two strings in C++

Tags: c++, string, spell-checking

I am building a small project for spelling correction, this is not homework.

Given two strings str1 and str2. One has to find out the number of characters matching between two strings.

For example if str1 = "assign" and str2 = "assingn", then the output should be 6.

In str2, characters, "a", "s", "s", "i", "g", "n" are there in str1, "assign". Thus output should be 6.

If str1 = "sisdirturn" and str2 = "disturb", then output should be 6.

In the str2, characters, "d", "i", "s", "t", "u", "r" are there in string str1, "sisdirturn". Thus output should be 6.

I've tried many attempts, however I am unable to get the answer. Kindly help to sort this out and if there is any idea to improve upon this, do tell.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
int char_match (string str1, string str2)
{
    //Take two strings, split them into vector of characters and sort them.
    int i, j, value = 0;
    vector <char> size1, size2;
    char* cstr1 = new char[str1.length() + 1];
    strcpy(cstr1, str1.c_str());
    char* cstr2 = new char[str2.length() + 1];
    strcpy(cstr2, str2.c_str());

    for(i = 0, j = 0 ; i < strlen(cstr1), j < strlen(cstr2); i++, j++)
    {
        size1.push_back( cstr1[i] );
        size2.push_back( cstr2[j] );
    }

    sort (size1.begin(), size1.end() );
    sort (size2.begin(), size2.end() );

    //Start from beginning of two vectors. If characters are matched, pop them and reset the counters.
    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    while ( !size1.empty() )
    {
        out :
        while ( !size2.empty() )
        {

            if (size1[i] == size2[j])
            {
                value++;
                pop_front(size1);
                pop_front(size2);
                i = 0;
                j = 0;
                goto out;
            }
            j++;    
        }
        i++;
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the number of characters matching" ? In particular what does matching mean in this context?

Comment: @Veritas For example if str1 = "assign" and str2 = "assingn", then the output should be 6.

In str2, characters, "a", "s", "s", "i", "g", "n" are there in str1, "assign". Thus output should be 6.

If str1 = "sisdirturn" and str2 = "disturb", then output should be 6.

In the str2, characters, "d", "i", "s", "t", "u", "r" are there in string str1, "sisdirturn". Thus output should be 6.

Comment: If you have strings "a" and "aaa" should that return 1 or 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // sort, set_intersection

std::string::size_type matching_characters(std::string s1, std::string s2) {
  sort(begin(s1), end(s1));
  sort(begin(s2), end(s2));
  std::string intersection;
  std::set_intersection(begin(s1), end(s1), begin(s2), end(s2),
                        back_inserter(intersection));
  return intersection.size();
}

int main() {
  std::cout << matching_characters("assign", "assingn") << '\n';     // 6
  std::cout << matching_characters("sisdirturn", "disturb") << '\n'; // 6
}
```

The above uses sort and so it has O(N*log N) performance, if that matters. If all your inputs are small then this may be faster than the second solution:

Sora's solution has better complexity, and can also be implemented concisely using standard `<algorithm>`s:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // for_each
#include <numeric>   // inner_product

int matching_characters(std::string const &s1, std::string const &s2) {
  int s1_char_frequencies[256] = {};
  int s2_char_frequencies[256] = {};
  for_each(begin(s1), end(s1),
           [&](unsigned char c) { ++s1_char_frequencies[c]; });
  for_each(begin(s2), end(s2),
           [&](unsigned char c) { ++s2_char_frequencies[c]; });

  return std::inner_product(std::begin(s1_char_frequencies),
                            std::end(s1_char_frequencies),
                            std::begin(s2_char_frequencies), 0, std::plus<>(),
                            [](auto l, auto r) { return std::min(l, r); });
}

int main() {
  std::cout << matching_characters("assign", "assingn") << '\n';     // 6
  std::cout << matching_characters("sisdirturn", "disturb") << '\n'; // 6
}
```

I'm using C++14 features, such as generic lambdas, for convenience. You may have to make some modifications if your compiler doesn't support C++14.

---

For me the solution using `sort` and `set_intersection` takes about 1/4th the time as the other solution for these inputs. That's because sorting and iterating over arrays of 6 or 7 elements can be faster than having to walk over arrays of 256 elements.

[`sort`/`set_intersection` (3667ns)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfd65f73dc7f4acb) vs. [`for_each`/`inner_product` (16,363ns)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8c88d5c1ad3c5aa)

Once the input is large enough the speed advantage will tip the other way. Furthermore, at the point where the input is too large to take advantage of the small-string optimization then the `sort`/`set_intersection` method will start doing expensive memory allocations.

Of course this performance result is highly implementation dependent, so if the performance of this routine matters you'll have to test it yourself on your target implementation with real input. If it doesn't matter then the O(N) solution is the better choice.

Comment: You stolen my answer! Btw, maybe it's better to use `std::vector` for storring `intersection` (with `intersection.reserve(s1.size()`), but it's not so important

Comment: @user2451677 `std::string` has a `reserve()` method as well. I want to use `std::string` because implementations support the `small string optimization', which allows allocation to be entirely avoided for small inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% on what it is you are actually trying to achieve, but in the case of trying to see how many characters that match in the words, it would be a simple case of just running a loop through them and adding 1 every time you found a match, like this

```
int char_match (string str1, string str2)
{
    //Take two strings, split them into vector of characters and sort them.
   unsigned int matches = 0;

   unsigned int stringLength = (str1.length > str2.length) ? str2.length : str1.length;

   for(unsigned int i = 0; i < stringLength; ++i)
   {
       if(str1[i] == str2[i])
       {
           ++matches;
       }
   }

    return matches;
}
```

but from your code it looks like you want to find out exactly how many of the same characters they have that is to say ignoring the actual position of each character then it would be a rather different process. Something along the lines of this

```
int char_match (string str1, string str2)
{
    unsigned int str1CharCount[256] = {0};
    unsigned int str2CharCount[256] = {0};

    unsigned int matches = 0;

   for(unsigned int i = 0; i < str1.length; ++i)
   {
       ++str1CharCount[static_cast<unsigned short>(str1[i])];
   }

   for(unsigned int i = 0; i < str2.length; ++i)
   {
       ++str2CharCount[static_cast<unsigned short>(str1[i])];
   }

   for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
   {
       matches += (str1CharCount[i] > str1CharCount[i]) ? str1CharCount[i] - (str1CharCount[i] - str2CharCount[i]) : str2CharCount[i] - (str2CharCount[i] - str1CharCount[i]);
   }

    return matches;
}
```

please note that for this second function there are probably a lot more efficient ways of doing it, but it should work all the same

EDIT:

This code should do what you wanted, main difference being it checks the ascii value to make sure it is a valid character

```
int char_match (string str1, string str2)
{
    unsigned int str1CharCount[256] = {0};
    unsigned int str2CharCount[256] = {0};

    unsigned int matches = 0;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < str1.length; ++i)
    {
        unsigned short aValue = static_cast<unsigned short>(str1[i]);
        if(aValue >= static_cast<unsigned short>('a') && aValue <= static_cast<unsigned short>('z'))
        {
            ++str1CharCount[static_cast<unsigned short>(str1[i]) - 32];
        }
        else if(aValue >= static_cast<unsigned short>('A') && aValue <= static_cast<unsigned short>('Z'))
        {
            ++str1CharCount[static_cast<unsigned short>(str1[i])];
        }
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < str2.length; ++i)
    {
        ++str2CharCount[static_cast<unsigned short>(str1[i])];
    }

    for(unsigned int i = static_cast<unsigned short>('a'); i <= static_cast<unsigned short>('Z'); ++i)
    {
        matches += (str1CharCount[i] > str1CharCount[i]) ? str1CharCount[i] - (str1CharCount[i] - str2CharCount[i]) : str2CharCount[i] - (str2CharCount[i] - str1CharCount[i]);
    }

    return matches;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although, I want to find out the number of characters matching between 2 strings. Like If str1 = "sisdirturn" and str2 = "disturb", then output should be 6. One may have to sort, to avoid irrelevant characters.

Comment: To resolve this instead of just doing a ++ on the str1||2charcount, you would place an if around to check that the value of the current char was > 64 and < 91 or > 96  and < 123, which would only give you characters between A-Z and a-z, then if you wanted to ignore, capitals so it only depended on the letter, all you would have to do was if it was > 96 and < 123, you would make it "++str1CharCount[static_cast<unsigned short>(str1[i]) - 32" and then the same for str2CharCount, after which you could just set the bottom for loop to start at 65 and continue until i < 91